# Lebesgue measurability criterion

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am stuck with proving the following theorem.

$A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and a closed set $F \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $F \subseteq A \subseteq U$ such that $m(U \setminus F) < \varepsilon$.

I have managed to prove the case when $A$ is bounded. But I have struggled to prove the case when $A$ is unbounded. Here is how far I managed to get.

Assume $A$ is Lebesgue measurable and unbounded, then as I proved the case for bounded $A$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist an open set $U_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and an closed set $F_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $F_n \subseteq A \cap [-n,n] \subseteq U_n$ such that $m(U_n \setminus F_n) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}$ for every natural number $n$. So I was told to let $U = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$ and $F = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(F_n \cap ([-n,-n+1] \cup [n-1,n]))$.

It is easy to see $U$ is open as $U$ is the union of open sets. But I struggle to see why $F$ is closed. Here is my attempt.

$[-n,-n+1] \cup [n-1,n]$ is closed because a finite union of closed sets is closed, then $F_n \cap ([-n,-n+1] \cup [n-1,n])$ is also closed since the intersection of closed sets is closed. But then why is $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(F_n \cap ([-n,-n+1] \cup [n-1,n]))$ is also closed?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What definition of Lebesgue measure are you using?

Comment: @cmk Thank you for your reply. I use the equality of the inner and outer measures.

Comment: But my biggest concern is that I don't understand why $F$ is closed. So I thought it wouldn't be important to specify the definition of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: the union of a locally-finite collection of closed sets is closed. The current answer is based on this idea, and without reading all details I would think it ought to be correct. The union of two closed sets is closed, and "locally" you are only taking unions of two closed sets. This is so because each point has a neighborhood that intersects at most two of the sets $[-n,-n+1] \cup [n-1,n]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $R_n := F_n\cap ([-n,-n+1]\cup [n-1,n])$ and let $(x_k)$ be a sequence in $F$ (the union) which converges to some $x$. We have to show that $x\in F$. Assume, e.g., that $x\in (n-1,n)$ for some $n > 0$. Then also $x_k\in (n-1,n)$ for $k\ge K$, so $x_k\in R_n$ for $k\ge K$ (it must be in some $R_\ell$ and only $R_n$ is possible). Hence, $x\in R_n\subset F$ since $R_n$ is closed. You can do the same for $x\in (-n,-n+1)$, of course.

So, you still have to figure out how to deal with the case that $x = n$ is an integer. But you can use the same principle here with the exception that in the end $x\in R_{n-1}\cup R_n\cup R_{n+1}$ is possible.

Comment: My sincere apologies for accepting this so late. I didn't have a clue at first then I took the time to understand this and now I understand it. Thank you so much for this brilliant explanation.